# Django urls - which view will be first if url is similar?

Tags: django

My URL:

/test/1/24-25-06-2016/

```
url(r'^test/(?P<item>\w+)/(?P<added>[-\w]+)/$', ItemView.as_view(), name='item'),
url(r'^test/(?P<item>\w+)/24-25-06-2016/$', ItemViewOther.as_view(), name='item-other'),
```

views.py

```
class ItemView(FormView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not int(self.kwargs['item']) in [1, 2, 3]:
            raise Http404
        if not self.kwargs['added'] in [
            '20-21-06-2016',
            '22-23-06-2016',
        ]:
            raise Http404
```

Why I get `404`? It should return `ItemViewOther` view I think.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django always matches in order. Since `[-\w]+` matches `24-25-06-2016`, the first pattern will be used.

Comment: How can I get around this? So this url `/test/1/24-25-06-2016/` should return `ItemViewOther`

Comment: Then put it first.